# Help with clean Kubuntu install on windows 11

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu

I want to switch from Windows 11 to Kubuntu. I installed the ISO and used rufus to create the boot drive. I have 2 drives, a C drive with windows 11 and a secondary drive, both are nvme ssd, and this is on the Dell xps 15 9500. When I tried to install Kubuntu, I got ubi-partman failed exit code 141, and when I went to the partition manager it only detected the flash drive, not the other drives. I selected the default option for the drive, which doesn't require manual partitioning because my goal was to have a clean install, deleting all of my files and windows 11 in the process. I can still go back to windows, which is able to detect my partitions. I'm not sure what route I'm supposed to go. I don't want to dual boot, I just want to clean install.

Comment: Boot from the LiveUSB and run Gparted. Does it show the SSD?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you still boot your Windows 11? If yes go to disk manager and see if both SSD's are there. Also check the Checksum of the written USB device. If that is correct boot from the USB device and choose try Kubuntu. With GParted ( as mentioned by Pilot6 ) or Disks you can check if your drives are recognized. If yes, check if the rest of your hardware works. Then install Kubuntu. If you can edit your question and mention which version of Kubuntu you are to install it would make troubleshooting easier for the community.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware & if SSD, its firmware? Did you change drive setting in UEFI to AHCI? (if Windows dual boot you need Windows ACHI drivers). What version of Kubuntu? You need latest since newer system. And choose safe boot & install optional restricted drivers in UEFI boot mode,. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview General Dell info: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467629&p=14061395#post14061395

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, but I resolved this issue awhile ago, I had to change from UEFI to AHCI, surprisingly someone already answered with this solution the day I posted it, but it seems that this website's notification system isn't exactly great